# File saved to Program files folder is not there

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I linked my application with the following options and saved a file from the application to the location `'C:\Program Files\ICEHost\Projects'`. The file saved without any issues. But when I open the folder the file is not there.[image]

I don't want to execute the application as run as administrator. How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your files had been virtualized:

http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Protecting-System-Files-UAC-Virtualization-Part1.html

Check if you have "Compatibility Files" option in Windows Explorer (in C:\Program Files\ and then with that option on navigate to your folder)

BTW, you souldn't save files to that location! Use User AppData folder instead.

Comment: Note that the Compatibility Files button is only available in Windows Vista and Windows 7. In Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 10 or later, the button has been removed. To view any compatibility files, you have to navigate manually to the folders as mentioned above:

%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\